# How to add handles to glass Justis doors?

Tags: drill, cabinets, glass

We just bought a condo - the kitchen has the Ikea Rubik horizontal pull-up glass doors (now known as the Justis glass doors). With me being on the shorter side, it's hard for me to open without using some kind of pull / handle.

The sellers left behind the handles that go with the set (formerly Blanket, now called Billsbro). But the frame of the door is aluminum with the middle being glass?

How do I drill holes in the metal without shattering the glass? Or should I try affixing the handles with epoxy as adhesive instead?

Not sure if there's a special trick for adding these handles. (sorry I'm not a handy person!)

(link to products for reference)

cabinet door: https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/sektion-wall-cab-horiz-2-gls-drs-w-push-op-white-jutis-frosted-glass-s69394815/ (photo even shown with handle)

handles: https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/billsbro-handle-stainless-steel-color-60323592/

Comment: https://www.ikea.com/us/en/assembly_instructions/jutis-glass-door__AA-504556-2_pub.PDF

Answer (score 2):

I have those doors in my IKEA furnished kitchen.
The doors are aluminum frames with a glass center panel.
As the directions (that Ecnerwal linked in a comment) show, you can carefully drill into the aluminum frame at the locations they show measurements for, and not hit the glass.  Use the handle as a template, and stay 2" away from the corner edge.